# How to prevent deselection in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, selection

I want that at any given moment some row is selected in a DataGrid. I don't want it to allow deselection. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAML

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">
    ...           
</DataGrid>
```

C#

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(
    object sender,
    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid g = sender as DataGrid;
    if (g != null &&
        e.AddedItems.Count == 0 &&
        e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
        {
            g.SelectedItem = (Device)e.RemovedItems[0];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried with `e.AddedItems.Count == 0` but when I use `e.RemovedItems.Count > 0` it yields an infinite loop and a StackOverflowException

Comment: I would expect that because setting the SelectedItem triggers the selection changed event, and without making sure there is not already a selection (i.e. `e.AddedItems.Count == 0`) the assignment will trigger the handler indefinitely.

Comment: what happens when you add `e.AddedItems.Count == 0`? does it work?

Comment: it works with `e.AddedItems.Count == 0` and `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`